# array schema single value mongodb using node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to fetch single value from my level collection using this level schema

After new Schema I use ( [] ) I don't know exactly the use of this. Why we use this. But my project requirement is to use this []

```
var LevelSchema = new Schema(
  [
   {
  _id: { type: String },
  age: { type: Number },
  level_num: { type: Number },
  min_score: { type: Number },
  max_questions: { type: Number }
  }
  ]);
```

So when I am trying to fetch the value using this node js

```
 this.levelChange = function(req, res, next){

  try{

   var query = {level_num:1};
   QuizLevels.find(query,function(err,data){
   if(err){
   return next(err);
   }else if(data.min_score===10){
   console.log(data.min_score);
  }else{
  console.log("Error");
   }
   });
  }catch(err){
  console.log(err);
     }
    };
```

I proper send all level information stored in my MongoDB to the browser. But when I am trying to fetch a single value field
min_score from the database and trying to send it in the browser or in the console it shows undefined. Means value cannot parse properly from MongoDB
to browser or console using this node js code.

so there are any further steps before to fetch this array schema.So that single value field parses properly to console

3). This is my JSON data

I am not sure that json data is exact according to level schema that i used to fetch.

```
   {
   "age":5,
   "level_num":1,
   "min_score":10,
   "max_questions":30
  }
   {
    "age":5,
    "level_num":2,
    "min_score":12,
    "max_questions":33
   }
```